# PHP file is not parsed after ">" operator

Tags: php

I've got a crucial problem with some php files after upgrading from php 5.3 to php 7 (but also to 5.6 or 5.5).

I use the operator ">" within a "if" block. It seems as if the server in this operator terminates the processing. The code behind this operator is displayed as normal HTML text.

For example. The following code

```
if ($value > 0) {
    echo "This is a test!";
}
```

leads to:

```
0){echo "This is a test!";}
```

What can I do to solve my problem?

Comment: You have an extra closing bracket

Comment: Now that would be a syntax error. If anything is shown at all, the real culprit resides before that. Wrong open tag. (Questions requiring guessing the full code are off-topic, btw.)

Comment: Thanks for the hints, but there is no extra bracket or something else within the if statement. Peculiarly it works on PHP 5.3. For now, I do not understand this error at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. 
There was a misconfiguration of the php.ini file. 
My predecessor activated the short_open_tag... and I do not.
Thank you all for the help!